# hapi : include a js custom library

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

In my index.js file I would like to load an external js library where I store functions. In the long run I would make it a module, but right now I need to get things prototyped. It's not part of node so I can't put it into `node_modules`. What's the command?

I have `index.js` and I have `functions.js` in the same folder.

Comment: What do you mean by an "external js library?"

Comment: See the edits of the text

Comment: `It's not part of node so I can't put it into node_modules`  What does that mean?  Are you saying it is not a module from npm or declared in `package.json`?

Comment: My previous questions aside, it's not clear what problem you are facing.  What have you tried and what problems have you encountered?

Comment: My problem is simply that I forgot how to do it properly because I have been using C++ and Python over the last months... I think the answer below is good enough. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[An explanation of how node loads modules via `require` is found here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules)

You have to specify a path (relative or absolute) to the file you want to include by starting the path with `/` or `./`

```
var functions = require("./functions");
```